# vb.net-how to create (insert elements) array but no repeated elements should be entered?

Tags: vb.net

VB.NET: How to create a program to insert 10 elements in an array?
How to create another array from it but no repeated number should be inserted?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of the concept:

```
    Dim ary(9) As String
    ary(0) = 1
    ary(1) = 3
    ary(2) = 5
    ary(3) = 4
    ary(4) = 6
    ary(5) = 4
    ary(6) = 3
    ary(7) = 8
    ary(8) = 9
    ary(9) = 3
    Dim newary() As String = ary.Distinct.ToArray
```

...but if you are not explicitly bound to using an array, a list would be much better. With an array, you'd have to limit yourself to the number of items you've instantiated the array with, or redim/resize it every time you add an element to it. A list wouldn't be limited like that and you could add new values on the fly.

Also, if all you need is distinct elements in the array, why not just check if your original array already contains a value before adding it, that way you skip having to copy the distinct values out of there..?

Answer (score 0):

Or use this:

```
Dim lst As New List(Of String)
    lst.AddRange({"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"})
    Dim array As String() = lst.ToArray
```

It does the same as the other answer but its smaller

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt get much shorter than this. You'll need to import Linq. array2 will contain 8 values since 1 and 9 are repeated.

```
Dim array1 As Integer() = {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9}
Dim array2 As Integer() = array.Distinct().ToArray()
```